# Extracting fee from Uniswap Swap event programmatically

Tags: uniswap

How one can calculate how much fees were paid to Uniswap (V2) like `Swap` transaction?

We get `amount0_in` and `amount1_in`, but then how we can know what was the output (`amount0_out`, `amount1_out`) without fees paid, because as far as I understand, the output comes with fees included?

Where in the Uniswap v2 source code does it deduct fees?

The same question for the newer version: where in Uniswap v3 source code it deducts fees?

```
    event Swap(
        address indexed sender,
        uint amount0In,
        uint amount1In,
        uint amount0Out,
        uint amount1Out,
        address indexed to
    );
```

Basically, I need to split this transaction to actual trade and fees paid (fees are tax deductible).

Comment: Not sure if this helps but I wrote a contract that does flash swaps on Uniswap V2. There's function in there called [getRepayWbtcAmount](https://github.com/hifi-finance/hifi-flash-swap/blob/a86af885218b25981b3ee67ee65137a3e7315600/contracts/HifiFlashSwap.sol#L26-L44) that adds the 0.3% fee on top of the amount of WBTC that I borrowed.

Comment: In Uniswap V2, the 0.3% fees are calculated in [getAmountIn](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/dda62473e2da448bc9cb8f4514dadda4aeede5f4/contracts/libraries/UniswapV2Library.sol#L52-L59) and [getAmountsOut](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/dda62473e2da448bc9cb8f4514dadda4aeede5f4/contracts/libraries/UniswapV2Library.sol#L62-L70).

Comment: Thank you @PaulRazvanBerg. So looks like if I multiply `amount0In` and `amount1In` with 0.997 I should get the "raw inventory" that went into the trade?

Comment: Yup. If that weren't the case, my flash loan execution would revert.